# Mouse cursor flickers and disappears, unknown display in display settings

Tags: ati, display, fglrx, cursor

I've just installed Ubuntu using the most recent ISO from online onto my desktop Computer. I have an AMD Radeon 6770 Graphics Card.

The cursor keeps flickering and disappearing on the screen. I also have an unknown display present when I look at my display settings. I have tried numerous fixes to get this to work but unfortunately none of them have worked. I installed fglrx which resulted in Ubuntu booting to a black screen.

When I go to the display preferences to remove the unknown display the program freezes when I select the display.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried to turn off screen number 2 in screen settings?